# Number of In Service Instances in ASG using boto3

Tags: boto3, instance, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics, autoscaling

I am trying to find out the number of in-service instances in an auto-scaling group using boto3. But, when the data is returned, the data points in the response are a null set. Previously, I used the same type of code to find out the number of messages in an SQS queue and it worked fine then. Here is the python code I have written

```
import boto3
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')

response3 = cloudwatch.get_metric_statistics(
    Namespace='AWS/AutoScaling',
    MetricName='GroupInServiceInstances',
    Dimensions=[
        {
            'Name': 'AutoScalingGroupName',
            'Value': 'onemoreASG'
        },
    ],
    StartTime=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes=1),
    EndTime=datetime.utcnow(),
    Period=60,
    Statistics=[
        'Maximum',
    ],
    Unit='Count'

)
datapoints2 = response3['Datapoints']
print(datapoints2)
```

Comment: Are metrics enabled for Autoscaling? https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.enable_metrics_collection

Comment: yes it was already enabled.

Answer (score 0):

When I removed the "Unit" parameter from the code, It is working fine.

```
import boto3
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
noi = 0.0
def numberofinstances(cloudwatch,noi):
    activeinstances = cloudwatch.get_metric_statistics(
        Namespace = 'AWS/AutoScaling',
        MetricName = 'GroupInServiceInstances',
        Dimensions=[
            {
                'Name': 'AutoScalingGroupName',
                'Value': 'ASGforSQS'
            },
        ],
        StartTime=datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes=1),
        EndTime=datetime.utcnow(),
        Period = 60,
        Statistics = [
            'Sum',
        ]
    )   
    values = activeinstances['Datapoints']
    for data in values:
        noi = data['Sum']
    return(noi)

result2 = numberofinstances(cloudwatch, noi)
print(result2)
```

Comment: Metrics are a unique combination of a Namespace, Metric Name, Dimensions (or lack of), and unit (or lack of).  If the metrics are pushed (by AutoScaling in this case) without a Unit, then you can't reference it with a unit, since CloudWatch would treat that as a completely different metric.

Comment: I thought the number of instances is a number and that is why I have used count in the initial code. But it didn't work and didn't return the no. of in-service instances. Later when I removed the unit parameter, It is working fine.

Comment: Its a bit unintuitive at first, but since the metric isn't pushed by the AutoScaling service with a unit, you have to leave unit blank.  Basically just have to look at the AWS docs (or the metric in the Cloudwatch console) any time your doing anything metric related to see if there's a unit and/or dimension(s)